# Scaling the screen in SUSE LEAP

Tags: suse

How can I downscale the screen size in SUSE LEAP, the desktop area is a bit oversized, this usually happened to be solved when I restarted the X server. But now since the propietary driver didn't work I had to go with an option provided by a gude.

Issue 1 catlyst works and allows me to check screens values and resolutions.

2 aticonfig says I have no adapter.